# Airflow parameter passing to Shell script

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to call shell script in my airflow DAG and passing few arguments as mentioned below,

```
def load_data_parameters():
   today_date = '{{ ds }}'
   environment = config.get('common', 'env') 
   return today_date,environment

today_date,environment = load_data_parameters()

EdgeToRaw_Command ="./scripts/test.sh"

Test = BashOperator(
        task_id= 'Test-Task',
        bash_command=EdgeToRaw_Command,
        params = {'env': environment},
        dag=dag)
```

In shell script just trying to print by,

```
envi=$1
echo $envi
```

Could someone help what is wrong in this or tell me how to pass parameter to the BashOperator which call's script to perform some task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shell script you need to have the following

```
envi={{params.env}}
echo $envi
```

Basically, whatever you pass to `params` argument in `BashOperator` is needed to be called by `{{params.PARAMETER_NAME}}`

Edit:

NOTE: Your "scripts" folder should be inside the same folder as your Dag file. So if you dag is under "/usr/local/airflow/dags", your "scripts" folder should be in the dame folder. And you need to pass the relative path in `bash_command` i.e. "scripts/test.sh"

Comment: do you have an idea how to pass more than one parameter or all the values of load_data_parameters to shell.

Comment: The params argument is a dictionary, hence it can have multiple values `params={"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}` and so on

Comment: this doesn't work with me ```t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='run_scripts',
        params={"source_user": var1},
        bash_command=exec_script
    )``` and on the bash script ```SOURCE_USER={{params.source_user}}
echo $SOURCE_USER```

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.  When I "echo $envi", the value printed is "{{params.env}}", the variable substitution doesn't occur.   It works correctly when bash_command calls a statement stored within the DAG .py file, but not when bash_command is an external .sh file.

Comment: Check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60403226/5691525