# Airflow BashOperator: Passing parameter to external bash script

Tags: bash, parameters, airflow

Having problems passing parameters to an external bash script from a BashOperator.
When I run a local command, the params are substituted correctly:

```
log_cleanup = """ echo "{{ params.BASE_LOG_FOLDER }}" """
log_cleanup_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='log_cleanup_task',
        provide_context=True,
        bash_command = log_cleanup,
        params = {'BASE_LOG_FOLDER': "/var/opt"},
        dag=dagInstance,
)

prints:  "/var/opt"   (without the double quotes)
```

But if I call an external bash script, the params don't substitute in.

```
log_cleanup_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='log_cleanup_task',
        provide_context=True,
        bash_command= str(DAGS_FOLDER)+"/scripts/log_cleanup.sh ",
        params = {'BASE_LOG_FOLDER': "/var/opt" },
        dag=dagInstance,
)

#log_cleanup.sh:
#! /usr/bin/bash
echo "{{ params.BASE_LOG_FOLDER }}"


prints: "{{ params.BASE_LOG_FOLDER }}"    (without the double quotes)
```

In the external bash script, I can't get the parameters to substitute in like they do when the statement is stored within the DAG .py script.

Do I have to pass the params as command line arguments instead? Does the jinja templating only works in the .py files?

Comment: What Airflow version do you use?

Comment: Airflow v.1.10.5

Comment: Can you please try the following in your Bash Script: `echo {{ params.BASE_LOG_FOLDER }}` i.e by removing quotes around it

Comment: ```[2020-02-25 21:10:36,904] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - {{ params.BASE_LOG_FOLDER }}```

Comment: Checking it now. Will update you soon

Comment: This had worked for me: `t3 = BashOperator( task_id='bash_print_date2', bash_command='kaxil.sh', params={"kaxil1": "hiiiikaxil"})` and `echo {{ params.kaxil1 }}` in `kaxil.sh`. Let me check because I know it definitely was a commaon gotcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space after `"log_cleanup.sh "` in `bash_command`

So your task should become:

```py
log_cleanup_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='log_cleanup_task',
        provide_context=True,
        bash_command= "scripts/log_cleanup.sh",
        params = {'BASE_LOG_FOLDER': "/var/opt" },
        dag=dagInstance,
)
```

**Note** that the **scripts** folder should be inside the folder containing your DAG file and it should contain the relative path to script (relative to folder containing this DAG)

The main reason you got `TemplateNotFound` error was the path mentioned in `bash_command` is not recognized by [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) (templating engine used by Airflow). Jinja only recognizes path passed in [DAG.template_searchpath](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG)
The default path is the folder containing the DAG so you can directly place your scripts folder under DAGs folder if your DAG is directly in the `$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags`. Or you can pass the path to your folder in DAG.template_searchpath as follows:

```py
dag = DAG("example_dag", template_searchpath="/var/opt/scripts")

# And then just pass "filename" to bash_command
log_cleanup_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='log_cleanup_task',
        provide_context=True,
        bash_command= "log_cleanup.sh ",
        params = {'BASE_LOG_FOLDER': "/var/opt" },
        dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: ```File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)```

Comment: @wolf2600 Check the note, update your bash_command to just `"scripts/log_cleanup.sh"` instead of `str(DAGS_FOLDER)+"/scripts/log_cleanup.sh` and make sure that your `scripts` folder is inside DAGs folder

Comment: Updated the answer with details

Comment: setting the command to:  "scripts/log_cleanup.sh" worked.  Not sure why using the relative path worked but using the absolute path (with DAGS_FOLDER from conf['core']) didn't.