# How to pass JSON variable to external bash script in Airflow BashOperator

Tags: bash, parameters, airflow-2.x

Here I am getting variables from Airflow GUI in form of JSON

```
example_vars=Variable.get("example_vars", deserialize_json=True)

dag = DAG('NEW_DAG', description='NEW_DAG', schedule_interval=None, default_args = default_args,catchup=False )

shell_command = 'path-to-my-file/my_script.sh '

running_task = BashOperator( task_id='task_to_run', bash_command=shell_command, trigger_rule="all_done",params={"val": example_vars}, dag=dag )

running_task
```

I tried from this page [Airflow BashOperator: Passing parameter to external bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402884/airflow-bashoperator-passing-parameter-to-external-bash-script)

in the bash script---->
echo {{ params.val }}

and it prints {{ params.val }} not the json file.

Comment: "But it does not seem to work" that's not enough...

Comment: Hi @DiegoTorresMilano
Thanks for pointing it out, i have updated the question with details.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
shell_command = 'path-to-my-file/my_script.sh "{{example_vars}}"'
```

See the examples at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it was not working although I did find an answer to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import shlex

# JSON variable
data = {'key': 'value'}

# Convert JSON variable to string
json_data = json.dumps(data)

# Quote the string to escape any special characters
escaped_json_data = shlex.quote(json_data)

# Pass the quoted string to the bash script
bash_command = './script.sh ' + escaped_json_data

# Create a BashOperator
bash_task = BashOperator(
   task_id='bash_task',
   bash_command=bash_command,
   dag=dag)
```

In bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
json_data=$1
```